# Logstash input plugin generator to generate dynamic data for elastic search

Tags: plugins, input, elasticsearch

I want to be able to generate large amount of data for a poc with Elastic Search. I came across this input plugin "generator". But from what I see in the documentation it can only generate statically specified data repeatedly. Does anyone know how to generate the dynamic data - that is it should emit new data everytime. I am referring to this `https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-generator.html`

Is it possible to use some kind of a regex in the value for "lines" .
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead on `generator` you can send random generated data to logstash with `tcp` input plugin

```
input { 
       tcp { type => "test" port => 50005 }
      }
```

Then send random data generated by `urandom` with `nc`:

```
cat /dev/urandom| tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9-_!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:<>?='|fold -w 100 | pv -L 20k | nc localhost 50005
```

`pv` will limit data rate `20KB/s`. Change the value accordingly for your need.
This ideal for testing since you can see how much data is fed to the logstash.